# Change frame and label colors on an item selected - syncfusion listview xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, frame, datatemplate, syncfusion

I have been trying to change the color of the first item of my list[0] and also when I tapped on an Item - the color I need to change is the frame and the labels inside it.

I tried the following: `BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"`

This works at the list level only, but nothing inside the data template. What else could I do?

what Im looking for , on selection change the border , background color and text 
[image]

```xml
<sync:SfListView x:Name="list" 
  SelectionMode="Single" 
  SelectionGesture="Tap" 
  ItemTapped="Day_ItemTapped">
    <sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>
        <Frame x:Name="frame"
          BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
          BorderColor="#D9DADB">
            <StackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding dayoftheweek}"  
               TextColor="{Binding textcolor}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
  </sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
</sync:SfListView>
```

-- @ Using template selector and frame , when you tapped the item again can comeback to its original colors ?

[image]

Comment: a couple of questions: are you binding the ItemSource to an observablecollection? (also, you ommited the ItemSource Binding), what are you doing in the ItemTapped event to change the colors? if IsActive starts with true value, does the color reflect the correct active color?

Comment: thanks@RicardoDiasMorais the itemsource is been called behind the page by only using the x:name .

Answer (score 2):

`SfListView` as `SelectedItemTemplate` and `HeaderTemplate` properties, which you could use you need separate template for selected item and need a header above `SfListView`.

But if Color change on Tap and separate Template for first item is what you require.

**For first item template**

1. Add a property for index in list item's model.
2. Use the index property in the template selector for deciding the template

**Xaml**

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstItem"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="FirstItem.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                   <Frame x:Name="frame"
                          BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Frame}"
                          BorderColor="#D9DADB">
                       <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                           <TapGestureRecognizer
                               Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                       </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                       <StackLayout>
                           <Label
                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                               BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Label}"/>
                       </StackLayout>
                   </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
               </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="firstTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
            <Label
                FontSize="32"
                Text="I'm Header"/>
                </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
       <ListView
           x:Name="listView">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <local:ListTemplateSelector
                   DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}"
                   FirstTemplate="{StaticResource firstTemplate}"/>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**TemplateSelector**

```cs
    public class ListTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate FirstTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            if(item != null)
            {
                ListItem listItem = (item as ListItem);
                if (listItem.Index == 0)
                {
                    return FirstTemplate;
                }
            }

            return DefaultTemplate;
        }
    }
```

**Populating the ListView**

```cs
    listView.ItemsSource = new List<ListItem>()
            {
                new ListItem(){Index=0, Name="Zero"},
                new ListItem(){Index=1, Name="One"},
                new ListItem(){Index=2, Name="Two"},
                new ListItem(){Index=3, Name="Three"},
                new ListItem(){Index=4, Name="Four"},
                new ListItem(){Index=5, Name="Five"},
                new ListItem(){Index=6, Name="Six"},
                new ListItem(){Index=7, Name="Seven"}
            };
```

ListView Item Model (ListItem.cs)

```cs
    public class ListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isActive;

        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return isActive;
            }
            set
            {
                isActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int index;

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return index;
            }
            set
            {
                index = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**For color change on tap**

1. Set a tap gesture for item layout
2. Set the IsActive property of the Item to true
3. Use IsActive property of the in the converter to change to required color.

**TapGesture:**

```cs
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((sender as Frame).BindingContext as ListItem).IsActive = !(((sender as Frame).BindingContext as ListItem).IsActive);
        }
```

ColorConverter:

```cs
    public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string sender = (string)parameter;
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return sender == "Frame" ? Color.Lime : Color.Red;
            }

            return Color.White;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! , I'm confused with ListItem is that the x:Name of the main list? and the template selector who is calling that ?

Comment: Ah.! I jus now noticed I didn't add the TemplateSelector usage example, added it now. `ListItem` is the Model(class) for ListView items not the ListView's x:Name.

Comment: Im still working on that. do you mind copy the full copy of the xaml . I just dont get the header part . Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: OK I'll add now

Comment: Sorry for been late. Im still confused on hows calling the public class ListTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector -> Template Selector

Comment: What is the namespace of the Template Selector?

Comment: Sorry, was away couldn't reply back. Just change the TapGesture event from setting to true to not of previous IsActive value. Is this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Check the TapGesture code I have changed to toggle IsActive property. Please do check in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207694/discussion-between-pxaml-and-nikhileshwar).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using Converter for BackgroundColor property of Frame and Label on ListView’s ItemTapped event. Please refer the following code snippet for more reference,

**Xaml**: Bind IsActive model property to BackgroundColor property of Frame and Label to change the color

```
<syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="dayslist" Margin="10" 
                               SelectionMode="Single"  
                               SelectionGesture="Tap" 
                               Orientation="Horizontal"  
                               ItemTapped="Dayslist_ItemTapped" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsInfo}"> 
<syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <Frame x:Name="frame" 
                           BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference frame}}" 
                           BorderColor="#D9DADB"> 
                        <StackLayout> 
                            <Label x:Name="label" Text="{Binding ContactName}" 
                                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference label}}"/> 
                        </StackLayout> 
                    </Frame> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate> 
</syncfusion:SfListView>
```

**C#**: Change the IsActive property value on ItemTapped event

```
    private void Dayslist_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var currentItem = e.ItemData as ListViewContactsInfo; 

        currentItem.IsActive = true; 

       //To reset the background color for previous selected item. 
        if (previousItem != null) 
        { 
            previousItem.IsActive = false; 
        } 

        previousItem = currentItem; 
    }
```

**Converter**: To return the color for Frame and Label based on selection

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
        var item = parameter as Frame; 
        ListViewContactsInfo model = null; 

        if (item != null) 
            model = (parameter as Frame).BindingContext as ListViewContactsInfo; 

        //To change the background color for item[0]. 
        if (model != null && model.Index == 0) 
            return Color.Red; 

        else 
        { 
            //To change the background color for Frame and Label. 
            if ((bool)value) 
                return parameter as Frame != null ? Color.Blue : Color.Yellow; 
        } 
        return Color.Transparent; 
    }
```