# Xamarin forms breadcrumbs with horizontal scroll layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app in which I am trying achieve a specific UI.Please find the attched image.

[image: Screenshot].

As you can see It is a list view and have a breadcrumbs below it. What I am trying to achieve is when user click any of the other items such as "stores" or "users" in breadcrumbs, then the upper layout horizontally slide and show another list view.Where I am stuck is I want to fix the breadcrumbs at the bottom and the change only needs the upper layout i.e.; the list view layout. How can I achieve this. Any ideas will be much helpfull.

What I am thinking is putting four listview inside horizontal scroll view.But is it the better approach?

Comment: Have you managed to slide the view? if not syncfusion's `SfRotator` could be useful to you. It takes care of the sliding part. Provide us what you have tried and achieved so for.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar Hi thanks for the reply. Currently it is only design. Is there any other control than syncfusion?

Comment: I don't know more about other controls. You can slide the view with Translate animations. But requires adding some logic to it. I'll try providing a solution.

Comment: you could look at TabbedPage, set the tab bottom,and change the content above,but if you want to achieve the effect above,you should custom the tab

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thanks for the idea. But I think it is not possible to acheive this Ui using tab, Right?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT is it possible to use contentview? Can I use listview inside contentview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by simple Translate animation.

A simple implementation of the idea of using translation. Change as per need.

XAML layout:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid x:Name="rotatingView">
        <ListView
            ...../>
        <ListView
            TranslationX="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference rotatingView}}"
            ...../>
        <ListView
            TranslationX="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference rotatingView}}"
            ...../>
        <ListView
            TranslationX="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference rotatingView}}"
            ...../>
    </Grid>
    <Button
        Text="0"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Button
        Text="1"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Button
        Text="2"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Button
        Text="3"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Xaml.cs clicked:

```
    int previousSelectedIndex = 0;

    private async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Button selectedtab = (sender as Button);
        int selectedViewIndex = int.Parse(selectedtab.Text);
        VisualElement previousView = rotatingView.Children[previousSelectedIndex];
        VisualElement selectedView = rotatingView.Children[selectedViewIndex];
        bool isMovingForward = true;

        if (previousSelectedIndex < selectedViewIndex)
        {
            isMovingForward = true;

        }
        else if(previousSelectedIndex > selectedViewIndex)
        {
            isMovingForward = false;
        }

        if (selectedViewIndex != previousSelectedIndex)
        {
            selectedView.TranslationX = rotatingView.Width * (isMovingForward ? 1 : -1);

            await Task.WhenAll(
                selectedView.TranslateTo(0, 0),
                previousView.TranslateTo(rotatingView.Width * (isMovingForward ? -1 : 1), 0));

        }

        this.previousSelectedIndex = selectedViewIndex;
    }
```

[image]

Here I have used the text of buttons to select index of the view. Hope this could help.

Comment: Where is the NRE thrown specifically?

Comment: Thansk bro for the answer. If you dont mind how can we change the clicked button color?

Comment: I could suggest a ListView and change the color as per the SelectedItem using TemplateSelector as you would also require to change color from selected to unselected. If possible check my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881543/change-frame-and-label-colors-on-an-item-selected-syncfusion-listview-xamarin)

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a breadcrumb navigation control.
I have created a control that will generate one automatically, and it's highly customisable.

https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Xamarin.Forms.Breadcrumb